# Power Query - For null, copy the contents of the row from the previous day

Tags: powerquery

I would like to achieve this effect

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyg2N.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIOCr.png)

Now my question is how to transform? solution to group data by date but I don't know what to do next, unfortunately I still lack the skills.

I would be very grateful for your help in solving this problem.

Comment: See [Fill values in a column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/fill-values-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Group By Date and Operation All Rows named "Product"
2. Replace **each _** with each **each if [Product] <> {null} then [Product] else null** and delete all the type table stuff in the Table.Group formula.

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date"}, {{"Product", each if [Product] <> {null} then [Product] else null}}})
```

3. Fill Down on the Product column
4. Expand The Product Column to New Rows

Key here is you need to replace a null list with just null so you can fill down.

See example
[image]

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMtQ31DcyUdJRMlSK1QFxjSBcKM8YwjNC5RpDuSYoak1ReGYQngmUaw6TjAUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, Product = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Product", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date"}, {{"Product", each if [Product] <> {null} then [Product] else null}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Grouped Rows",{"Product"}),
    #"Expanded Product" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Filled Down", "Product")
in
    #"Expanded Product"
```